# Weird spacing with awesome-cv

Tags: tables, spacing, awesome-cv

For some reason, there seems to be an abnormal indentation under the 'Interests' category. 'Skills' uses the same definition as 'Interests', but as you can see, the weird indentation is not there. I tried adding `\vspace` before the point but it didn't seem to do the trick. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Minimal starting code:

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\fontdir[fonts/]

\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}


\begin{document}
\cvsection{Skills}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {}
    {\def\arraystretch{1.15}{\begin{tabular}{ l l }
                Languages:  & ~~{\skill{ Python, JavaScript, Angular.js, Node.js, React/Redux, C++, C, Java, Scala}} \\
                Technologies:  & ~~{\skill{ PostgreSQL, MongoDB, TensorFlow, AWS, Heroku, Git, GCloud, CircleCI}} \\
    \end{tabular}}}
    {}
    {}
    {}
\end{cventries}
\vspace{-10mm}
\cvsection{Interests}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {}
    {\def\arraystretch{1.15}{\begin{tabular}{ l l }
                {\myskill{ Competitive Badminton, Snowboarding, Bouldering, Photography, Physical Fitness, Foosball, Exotic Cuisine}} \\
    \end{tabular}}}
    {}
    {}
    {}
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your given second table is an error: you defined two columns but used only one.

Perhaps you missed the leading category name or you simple need only one column. I assume the first one like

```
  \begin{tabular}{ p{2cm} p{12cm} }
   Test: & Competitive Badminton, Snowboarding, Bouldering, Photography, Physical Fitness, Foosball, Exotic Cuisine %\\
  \end{tabular}%
```

Please see that I used `p{12cm}` to get an column allowing breaking the line with an length of 12 cm. Please note that is this case I can alos omit your used `~~` in the first table, which does not allow line breakings.

Please see the following code

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\fontdir[fonts/]
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}


\begin{document}

\cvsection{Skills}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {}
    {\def\arraystretch{1.15}{%
      \begin{tabular}{ l l }
        Languages:    & ~~{Python, JavaScript, Angular.js, Node.js, React/Redux, C++, C, Java, Scala} \\
        Technologies: & ~~{PostgreSQL, MongoDB, TensorFlow, AWS, Heroku, Git, GCloud, CircleCI} %\\
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }
    {}
    {}
    {}{}
\end{cventries}
\vspace{-10mm}

\cvsection{Interests}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {}
    {\def\arraystretch{1.15}{%
      \begin{tabular}{ p{2cm} p{12cm} }
       Test: & Competitive Badminton, Snowboarding, Bouldering, Photography, Physical Fitness, Foosball, Exotic Cuisine %\\
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    }
    {}
    {}
    {}
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result]

BTW: you used two commands `\skill` and `\myskill` in your code you did not define in the given code. I deleted them. You forgot to add `\end{document}`. I added it.